# permantly apply style.format to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I went to apply a style.format to one of my columns in the df (to add commas), but after calling df second time –– it seems that the style.format is not permanent? When I do assign the style.format to a variable and then call it, it does work. BUT calling df.head(5) gives me `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'head'`

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10)
df = pd.read_excel('./resources/mycopy-copy.xlsx')
df <---#truncates here
df.style.format({'Number of Doses Procured': '{:,}'}) #or df = df.style.format({'Number of Doses Procured': '{:,}'})
df <---#spits out all 500 rows
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no, there is no way to "apply a style permanently to a `DataFrame`".

[Styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) is typically the last step before rendering (as HTML), although it can be composed by chaining.

The result of `df.style.anyfunction()` is a `Style` object. As such, it doesn't have the methods of `DataFrame`, in particular as per your question, `.head()`:

```py
>>> type(df.style.format('${:,.2f}'))
pandas.io.formats.style.Styler
```

The `DataFrame` doesn't know anything about any `Styler`. Instead, it is the `Styler` that has a reference to the `DataFrame` it was originally used for.

You can take the style itself and apply it to another `DataFrame` (with `Styler.use()` and `Styler.export()`, see below). **However**, regrettably, that doesn't seem to include `.format()` definitions (at least in `pandas=1.2.1`).

It's really too bad, because otherwise, it makes it quite easy to reuse a style for another DF (or `df.head()` per your example):

```py
def neg_red(x):
    return f"color: {'red' if x < 0 else 'black'}"

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-4, 5, (5, 3)) * 1e4)
s = df.style.format('${:,.2f}').applymap(neg_red).highlight_max()
s
```

[image]

Observe that: `assert vars(s)['data'] is df`. So as I said above, the `Styler` object has a reference (`data`) to the `DataFrame` it was used on initially (so that, when it is asked to render, it knows what data to render).

Now, you can use the `Styler` object and apply it to another `DataFrame` (here: `df.head(3)`):

```py
df.head(3).style.use(s.export())
```

[image]

As you can see, all the styling functions have been carried over, *except for the formatting*! I would imagine this is a bug or an oversight.