# Multiple formatting rules applied on HTML-exported DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, pandas-styles

I need to paste a `pandas` `DataFrame` into the HTML body of a newly generated email draft through a function. The problem is, I need to apply more than one conditional styling to it before it ends in the email draft.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

def create_mail(text, subject, recipient):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.save()

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Number': [100.00, -100.00], 'Date': [dt.date(2020, 1, 1), dt.date(2022, 1, 1)]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
```

The styles are defined as follows:

```
def style_negative(v, props = 'color:red;'):
    return props if v < 0 else None
def style_red_date(v, props = 'color:red;'):
    return props if v < dt.datetime.now().date() else None
```

Negative numbers in `Number` column must be colored red.
Dates falling before today in `Date` column must be colored red as well.

If I apply only one (either) style to the `DataFrame` object through `df.style.applymap()`, it works perfectly fine. However, when I want to apply another style to the (now) `Styler` object through `.apply()`

```
df = df.style.applymap(style_negative, subset = ['Number'])
df = df.apply(style_red_date, subset = ['Date'])
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The rest of my code:

```
html = (
    df
    .format({'Number':"{:.2f}"})
    .set_properties(**{'font-size':'11pt'})
    .hide_index()
    .render()
    )

mail_content = """
<html><head></head><body>
{0}
</body></html>
""".format(html)

create_mail(mail_content, "Subject", "")
```

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081411/permantly-apply-style-format-to-a-dataframe) question as to export a style from `Styler` object, but it seems that it can only be used on a `DataFrame` object. Is there a way to have multiple formatting rules applied to a `DataFrame` / `Styler` object and have it exported as HTML? Am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just need [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here instead of an inline `if else`.

Some other notes:

1. When creating a [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) object from [`DataFrame.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.style.html) we should save that as a variable called `styler` or something similar instead of `df` to denote the type of object has changed from [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) to [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html)
2. We do not need to assign back when working with adding additional styles to an already declared [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) object
3. We need [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create an [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) of styles based on all of the boolean values produced by doing boolean operations on a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html)
4. We should prefer the empty string (`''`) to represent no styles  over `None` (for consistent dtype processing)
5. Instead of tying to use python string formatting we should just use (as of pandas 1.3.0) [`Styler.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_html.html) with `doctype_html=True` instead of [`Styler.render`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render.html)

   - if needing more complex HTML manipulation a [Subclass](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Subclassing) should be used rather than attempting string manipulation on the results of [`render`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render.html)/[`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_html.html)

```py
# import numpy as np


def style_negative(v, props='color:red;'):
    return np.where(v < 0, props, '')


def style_red_date(v, props='color:red;'):
    return np.where(v < dt.datetime.now().date(), props, '')


styler = df.style.applymap(style_negative, subset=['Number'])
styler.apply(style_red_date, subset=['Date'])

mail_content = (
    styler
        .format({'Number': "{:.2f}"})
        .set_properties(**{'font-size': '11pt'})
        .hide_index()
        .to_html(doctype_html=True)
)
```

---

We can also do a single chain of styles like:

```
# Using same modified functions as above but as a function chain:
mail_content = df.style.applymap(
    style_negative, subset=['Number']
).apply(
    style_red_date, subset=['Date']
).format(
    {'Number': "{:.2f}"}
).set_properties(
    **{'font-size': '11pt'}
).hide_index().to_html(doctype_html=True)
```

These options produce the following HTML in `mail_content`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="">
  <style type="text/css">
    #T_0f6b6_row0_col0,
    #T_0f6b6_row1_col1 {
      font-size: 11pt;
    }
    
    #T_0f6b6_row0_col1,
    #T_0f6b6_row1_col0 {
      color: red;
      font-size: 11pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="T_0f6b6_">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col0">Number</th>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col1">Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="T_0f6b6_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0">100.00</td>
        <td id="T_0f6b6_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1">2020-01-01</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="T_0f6b6_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0">-100.00</td>
        <td id="T_0f6b6_row1_col1" class="data row1 col1">2022-01-01</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Setup:

```
import datetime as dt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Reproducible example with year offset so styles will always
# be reproducible same even in future years 
# (even though date values will change) 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Number': [100.00, -100.00],
    'Date': pd.to_datetime(
        [dt.date(dt.datetime.now().year - 1, 1, 1),
         dt.date(dt.datetime.now().year + 1, 1, 1)]
    ).date
})
```

Comment: Note for future ref `styler.render` is deprecated in favour of `styler.to_html` and the `doctype_html` kwarg is documented under `to_html`, if you wonder why you cant find it under `render`.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't fully updated all of my old practices since all the 1.3.0 changes. I appreciate the update. :-)

Comment: @HenryEcker, thank you very much, it works perfectly! Big thanks for the additional notes too, I really appreciate it.